# nested angular reactive form, how to use the form body details in ts file

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cuukb4

In this code,

I got values of first name, last name, and skills values by mapping
I need to pass these vals in body and iterate and display

```js
  const body = {
      displayText: true,
      employee: [
        {

          firstName: this.employeeFirstName(0).value,
          lastName: this.employeeLastName(0).value,
         skills: [
            {
             skill: this.getEmployeeSkill(0,0),
             exp: this.getEmployeeExp(0,0)
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
```

but this only gives me value for 0th employee and 0th skill, how do i make indices update and display them in my console.log(body).
displayText value does not change and remains same for every iteration

so currently employeeFirstName, employeeLastName, getEmployeeSkill, getEmployeeExp get me, first name, employee name, skill and exp data.

but they only return it for 0th index

expected result in const body..

```js
{
[
    {
          displayText: true,
          employee: [
            {

              firstName: 0th emp first name,
              lastName: 0th emp last name,
             skills: [
                {
                 skill: 0th employee 0th skill,
                 exp: 0th employee 0th exp
                },
                {
                 skill: 0th employee 1st skill,
                 exp: 0th employee 1st exp
                }
                .
                .
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
],
[
     {
          displayText: true,
          employee: [
            {

              firstName: 1st emp first name,
              lastName: 1st emp last name,
             skills: [
                {
                 skill: 1st employee 0th skill,
                 exp: 1st employee 0th exp
                },
                {
                 skill: 1st employee 1st skill,
                 exp: 1st employee 1st exp
                }
                .
                .
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
     ]
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what data you need to extract from your form? It would help if you update your quesiton with the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure that you're describing is the same as the structure of your form. Since this is the case, you can simply use the value of the `employees` `FormArray`.

Instead, you want to be able to build the `body` using the indices of the form arrays. To do this, you can use the `map` array function.

```js
employees(): FormArray {
  return this.empForm.get("employees") as FormArray
}

onSubmit() {
  const formEmployees: [] = this.employees().value;
  const employee = formEmployees
    .map((_, i: number) => this.mapFormEmployee(i));
  const body = {
    displayText: true,
    employee: employee
  };

  console.log(body);
}

private mapFormEmployee(empIndex: number): {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  skills: { skill: string; exp: string; }[];
} {    
  const employeeFormGroup = this.employees().at(empIndex);

  return {
    firstName: employeeFormGroup.get('firstName').value,
    lastName: employeeFormGroup.get('lastName').value,
    skills: employeeFormGroup.get('skills').value.map((_, skillIndex) => 
      this.mapFormSkill(empIndex, skillIndex)
    )
  };
}

private mapFormSkill(empIndex: number, skillIndex: number): { skill: string; exp: string } {
  const employeeFormGroup = this.employees().at(empIndex);
  const skillFormGroup = (employeeFormGroup.get('skills') as FormArray).at(skillIndex);

  return {
    skill: skillFormGroup.get('skill').value,
    exp: skillFormGroup.get('exp').value
  };
}
```

You haven't gone into detail about why you need to do it this way, but this is one way of building the `body` using indices.

It would help if you gave a reason why you want to extract data from the form in this way instead of mapping directly from `this.empForm.value`.

I am mapping the data in an inefficient way as I wanted to keep the functionality similar to how you are doing it at the moment.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rbd4mj

Comment: this does not apply to my requirements, I am trying to get all the values individually cuz i need to manipulate those,for my another code..is there a way for it to be displayed by updating indices

Comment: I have updated my answer. I'm sure you have a good reason for wanting to do it this way - it's certainly not the approach I would normally take.

Comment: skills: employee.map((skill, skillIndex) => ({
        skill: this.getEmployeeSkill(empIndex, skillIndex),
        exp: this.getEmployeeExp(empIndex, skillIndex)
      }))..in this mapping, it should be---- skills: employee.map((skills, skillIndex) =>

Comment: istead of skill it should be skills ? in the mapping function?

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. `skills` should map from `employee.skills.map`

Comment: (skill, skillIndex) this is inside mapping function, should it be (skills, skillIndex) istead?

Comment: it is not giving an output, also got an error saying the indices need to be number and not any..don't know whats wrong, mapping a data inside data is confusing

Comment: I was just adding to your code, which has a few issues. I have re-written the answer so it is self-contained. It would be really helpful if you stated why you want to map the data using indexes rather than directly from `empForm.value`, which would be much more efficient.

Comment: there's a code that i am working on, which is similar to this, and it need skill and exp data seperately, cuz i need to convert both the data into another data form

Comment: Does my updated version suit your needs? Your code needs a re-write, so I'm just trying to show you the **concept** of how you would approach this

Comment: in my code exp and skill are start time and end time respectively, and i need to convert them from 12hrs format to 24 hrs format, in order for api to accpt it and code to work

Comment: I will try to run it and let you know if it works, thank you

Comment: So why not just do that in a mapping function? Getting the value using an index is exactly the same as getting the values from `empForm.value`, I don't see how the index method is better?

Comment: your approach worked, thank you so much. could you please help with this query too, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60918771/not-able-to-get-values-from-ts-body-to-html-table-formarray-formgroup-angular